# Wordpress - Custom Post Types URL

Tags: php, wordpress

Sistema de Anúncios no Wordpress

**Categorias e Sub-categorias de Post (Estados / Cidades):**

- localhost/site/cidades/sp/sorocaba (exemplo)

**Custom Post Types:**

- Cupons: localhost/site/cupons/postname
- Anúncios: localhost/site/anuncios/postname
- Empresas: localhost/site/empresas/postname

**Cenário e dúvida:**

1. Usuário entrou no site
2. Usuário é obrigado escolher uma cidade e um estado
3. Usuário escolhe SP / Jundiaí e é redirecionado para: http://localhost/site/cidades/sp/sorocaba
4. Usuário visualiza tudo da página: anúncios, cupons, empresas, banners de Sorocaba.
5. Usuário clica no menu superior: CUPONS
6. Usuário é redirecionado para http://localhost/site/cupons

**Problema:**

7. Aí o site/sistema não sabe mais que ele estava em Sorocaba.

**O que eu precisava:**

Se quando o usuário selecionasse uma cidade, criasse uma Session ou Cookie ou qualquer outra coisa e ficasse "salvo" para o usuário entrar em Cupons e a query do wordpress pegasse $estado $cidade para fazer o filtro ai seria o mundo ideal!

Cliente não quer perder url amiável, sem get e parâmetros na url..

Alguém sabe resolver?

Comment: este *usuário* vai estar logado no wp?

Comment: Você pode criar essa session manual, depois no arquivo referente a página, pode alterar os parâmetros da $wp_query global..